# SQL stuck with this one

Tags: sql, db2

I need to select rows from a table where only one row exists with that ID.

Example Table, with two columns.
ID first and  timestamp.
so first row is ID 1,  Timestamp  01/01/2013

```
ID      Timestamp
1       01/01/2013
2       02/02/2013
3       04/02/2013
3       07/02/2013
4       20/03/2013
```

So, for this table I'd only like to return the records with ID 1,2,4 as these all have only 1 row.

I then need to only return these rows if they have a timestamp of more than one month ago.  The timestamp is in this format `2012-11-12-22.00.15.541231`

Can anyone help please?

Comment: which database you are using ?

Comment: `isqlquery` tag suggests SQL Server

Comment: What type is the `Timestamp` column?

Comment: Just querying a DB2 table, not sqlserver wrong tag sorry!

Comment: **`select ID from table_name group by ID having count(1)=1;`** Its in **SQL Server**. But you can refer the Logic.

Comment: Timestamp is a datetime data type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AND time_created < current_timestamp - 1 month
```

Comment: @Luv I think you are missing `NOT IN` clause.
with not in you have to use `count(*)>1` for the desired output.

Comment: Nope, `>1` when `NOT IN` used. It would be `=1` when `IN` used

Comment: OP also wants another condition.

Comment: Timestamp constraint was NOT present in first revision of this question. Added.

Comment: Time check should be `<` "only return these rows if they have a timestamp of more than one month ago"

Comment: Thanks for the help, and for being so quick too!  Nice one!  I'll give it a shot...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `group by` clause for this output -

**Edit**

adding [Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893874/sql-stuck-with-this-one/16894095?noredirect=1#comment24377371_16894095) on datestamp column

```
SELECT *
  FROM Your_Table_Name
 WHERE Id IN
       (SELECT Id FROM Your_Table_Name GROUP BY Id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
 AND time_created < current_timestamp - 1 month
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
select id
from yourtable
where timestampfield <= current timestamp - 1 month
group by id
having count(*) = 1
```

The minus 1 month part came from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html).

Comment: It should probably check the count first, and the date condition after

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd85e6/11)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ID` int, `Timestamp` date)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ID`, `Timestamp`)
VALUES
    (1, '2013-01-01'),
    (2, '2013-02-02'),
    (3, '2013-04-02'),
    (3, '2013-07-02'),
    (4, '2013-03-20')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select ID,Timestamp
from Table1
where DATEDIFF(curdate(),DATE_SUB(Timestamp,INTERVAL 1 MONTH))>=1
group by ID
having count(ID)=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd85e6/11/0)**:

```
| ID |                       TIMESTAMP |
----------------------------------------
|  1 |  January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  2 | February, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  4 |    March, 20 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: this question has nothing to do with MySQL

Comment: @mvp : just wanted to show the approach. It's common for all the databases i guess and when i looked into the problem there was no tag associated for the database so i considered mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to return IDs and timestamps, you can avoid using a subquery, going like this:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(Timestamp) AS Timestamp
FROM atable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
   AND MAX(Timestamp) < CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 1 MONTH
;
```